# How do I give boolean value to decide is my timestamp is holiday and weekends or not in Dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, calendar

I have a dataframe calendar, it contains date and is holiday or not.

I have another dataframe contains datetime timestamp, and i want to check each is holiday or not (weekends as well).

How could I do it?

for example this is my calendar:

```
  0     2015-01-01           1                       New Year's Day
  1     2015-04-03           1             Good Friday (Karfreitag)
  2     2015-04-05           1         Easter Sunday (Ostersonntag)
  3     2015-04-06           1          Easter Monday (Ostermontag)
  4     2015-04-27           1             King's Day (Netherlands)
  5     2015-05-04           1                      Remembrance Day
  6     2015-05-05           1                       Liberation Day
  7     2015-05-14           1  Ascension Day (Christi Himmelfahrt)
  ... ...
```

This is my dataframe:

```
  0     2015-01-01 06:00:00        88  ...        6.0    
  1     2015-01-01 07:00:00        86  ...        5.8    
  2     2015-01-01 08:00:00        86  ...        5.3    
  3     2015-01-01 09:00:00        84  ...        5.5   
  4     2015-01-01 10:00:00        81  ...        5.6     
  5     2015-01-01 11:00:00        78  ...        5.8   
  6     2015-01-01 12:00:00        76  ...        6.0     
  7     2015-01-01 13:00:00        74  ...        5.5     
  8     2015-01-01 14:00:00        73  ...        6.3      
  9     2015-01-01 15:00:00        73  ...        6.5     
  10    2015-01-01 16:00:00        73  ...        6.7     
  11    2015-01-01 17:00:00        73  ...        7.1     
  12    2015-01-01 18:00:00        73  ...        7.6     
  13    2015-01-01 19:00:00        73  ...        8.1     
  14    2015-01-01 20:00:00        74  ...        8.6     
  15    2015-01-01 21:00:00        75  ...        9.1     
  16    2015-01-01 22:00:00        75  ...        9.3     
  17    2015-01-01 23:00:00        78  ...        9.6     
  18    2015-01-02 00:00:00        84  ...        9.8          
  19    2015-01-02 01:00:00        86  ...        9.9    
  20    2015-01-02 02:00:00        87  ...        9.9
```

This is what i want:

```
  0     2015-01-01 06:00:00        88  ...        6.0    1
  1     2015-01-01 07:00:00        86  ...        5.8    1
  2     2015-01-01 08:00:00        86  ...        5.3    1
  3     2015-01-01 09:00:00        84  ...        5.5    1
  4     2015-01-01 10:00:00        81  ...        5.6    1
  5     2015-01-01 11:00:00        78  ...        5.8    1
  6     2015-01-01 12:00:00        76  ...        6.0    1
  7     2015-01-01 13:00:00        74  ...        5.5    1
  8     2015-01-01 14:00:00        73  ...        6.3    1
  9     2015-01-01 15:00:00        73  ...        6.5    1
  10    2015-01-01 16:00:00        73  ...        6.7    1
  11    2015-01-01 17:00:00        73  ...        7.1    1
  12    2015-01-01 18:00:00        73  ...        7.6    1
  13    2015-01-01 19:00:00        73  ...        8.1    1
  14    2015-01-01 20:00:00        74  ...        8.6    1
  15    2015-01-01 21:00:00        75  ...        9.1    1
  16    2015-01-01 22:00:00        75  ...        9.3    1
  17    2015-01-01 23:00:00        78  ...        9.6    1
  18    2015-01-02 00:00:00        84  ...        9.8    0  
  19    2015-01-02 01:00:00        86  ...        9.9    0
  20    2015-01-02 02:00:00        87  ...        9.9    0
```

I want to add one colunm and mark `2015-01-01` as `1` and `2015-01-02` as `0`
also when the datetime appear to be as a weekend it should also be 
marked as `1`

Answer (score 0):

To get the 1s from your calendar, you could merge the dfs, for which you should create a column with only the date (not date and time) in the df, so it matches the format from your calendar.

To know wether the day is weekday or not, you could check so with [pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this. One is with [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df['Holiday'] = df['date'].dt.date.astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(calendar['date'].astype(str))).astype(int)

print(df)
                  date  val1  val2  Holiday
0  2015-01-01 06:00:00    88   6.0        1
1  2015-01-01 07:00:00    86   5.8        1
2  2015-01-01 08:00:00    86   5.3        1
3  2015-01-01 09:00:00    84   5.5        1
4  2015-01-01 10:00:00    81   5.6        1
5  2015-01-01 11:00:00    78   5.8        1
6  2015-01-01 12:00:00    76   6.0        1
7  2015-01-01 13:00:00    74   5.5        1
8  2015-01-01 14:00:00    73   6.3        1
9  2015-01-01 15:00:00    73   6.5        1
10 2015-01-01 16:00:00    73   6.7        1
11 2015-01-01 17:00:00    73   7.1        1
12 2015-01-01 18:00:00    73   7.6        1
13 2015-01-01 19:00:00    73   8.1        1
14 2015-01-01 20:00:00    74   8.6        1
15 2015-01-01 21:00:00    75   9.1        1
16 2015-01-01 22:00:00    75   9.3        1
17 2015-01-01 23:00:00    78   9.6        1
18 2015-01-02 00:00:00    84   9.8        0
19 2015-01-02 01:00:00    86   9.9        0
20 2015-01-02 02:00:00    87   9.9        0
```

---

**Note** Since you didn't include column names, I made them myself, so you have to change them to the correct ones.

**Explanation**

`dt.date` returns the date without the time:

```
df['date'].dt.date.head()

0    2015-01-01
1    2015-01-01
2    2015-01-01
3    2015-01-01
4    2015-01-01
Name: date, dtype: object
```

---

`'|'.join()` returns your calender dates as a string delimited by a pipe `|` which is the *or* operator in `regex`:

```
'|'.join(calendar['date'].astype(str))

'2015-01-01|2015-04-03|2015-04-05|2015-04-06|2015-04-27|2015-05-04|2015-05-05|2015-05-14'
```

Comment: This helps!and i could also understand your explaination very well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But how could i check weekends at the same time but not overwrite the result about what i have checked for calendar?